# how to work on JList

Tags: java, swing

I want to add files in `JList` and when user selects the file and clicks open then he should be able to open that selected.

I am trying to code this, will I be able to only display the path of the file in the list? So that when user clicks then we get that path where user clicked and open the file.

If so then, is it possible to list only the filename and not its paths so that even then when user  clicks on that file name he should be able to open it.

If its possible just tell me how to do it na.. I don't want coding i just need a practical idea on this..i am coding all this using java..

Comment: Your JList can display as much or as little information as you want. Look into creating a ListCellRenderer, such as a DefaultListCellRenderer, for it. The tutorials will show you how.

Answer (score 2):

Get a list of `File` objects.  Place these in some kind of `ListModel`, `DefaultListModel` should be capable of supporting this functionality.

Design a `ListCellRenderer` which is capable of returning the visual representation of what you want displayed.  I'd use something like `DefaultListCellRenderer`, which is based on a `JLabel`, but has inbuilt support for selection formatting, you would simply need to call `setText` after you've used the `super` implementation.

You can use a `ListSelectionListener` to monitor changes to the list's selection and disable/enable the open button.

When the user clicks the open button, you can get the currently selected item from the `JList`, which will return a `File` reference (from you model).

You can then use [`java.awt.Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) to open it

Take a closer look at [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [How to intergrate with the Desktop class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) for more details